# VScode закомментировать блок кода

Tags: visual-studio-code

Как взять огромные куски кода в комментарии с помощью горячих клавиш?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `Ctrl + /` должен работать

Answer (score 2):

Несколько способов, но сначала выделите блок, который будете комментить:

1. По умолчанию на Windows <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, для OS X <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd> + <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.
   Поскольку я, например, использую `Azure` расширение, то данная комбинация переопределяется под него, поэтому данное сочетание клавиш может не работать. В этом случае можно назначить собственные горячие клавиши через интерфейс, который открывается при помощи <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>
2. Через `Command Palette`
   <kbd>F1</kbd> или Win:<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> или OS X:<kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd> + <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
   В строке ввести: `Toggle Block Comment`, выбрать и нажать <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Через пользовательский интерфейс
   `File` -> `Edit` -> `Toggle Block Comment`

Результат будет отличаться для разных языков. Удобное использование заключается еще и в том, что при использовании данных горячих клавиш на закомментированых блоках, они будут раскомменчиваться.

Примеры

Python

```py
""" import requests


for f in range(10):
    print(f) """
```

Javascript

```js
/* let range = {
    start: new Date(),
    end: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 150)),
}; */
```

C

```c
/* typedef enum
{
     INIT = 0
    ,DRAW
    ,PROCESSING
    ,EXIT
}eGameState; */
```

и тд

Answer (score 0):

Это называется многострочный комментарий, в python это ''' в начале и конце нужного кода, к примеру:

```
'''print('assd')
   print('dasd')'''
```

Comment: я имел ввиду как взять все в комментарий вот так

Comment: # x = 5
# y = "John"
# print(x)
# print(y)

Comment: Так это тоже самое, только каждую строку, вы выделяете нужный код и три раза нажимаете '

Comment: @MuzaffarxonSolixonov, https://www.kindacode.com/article/vs-code-how-to-comment-out-a-block-of-python-code/ . Но чаще многострочные комментарии как в данном ответе - более читабельные.

Comment: Это не многострочный комментарий. Это многострочный литерал строки, в частности он используется для документации, но как правило не используется для комментирования. В целом, этот ответ не отвечает на вопрос.